# Good examples of governmental digital products

Tags: usability, ux-field, government

I'm trying to find good examples of governmental digital products (such as mygov, personal portal, websites, digital forms etc).

One of my favorites is [Califonia's DMV website](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/?fbclid=IwAR33mppdGWVfd2Z1ue_oGg7-XQtTSenYTUWvkn6YZhTzfLQRBIcX1M1nLqM)

How well-designed are digital products in your country? Can you please share print-screens personalized pages (after log-in).

Thanks <3

Comment: This includes a very wide scope of products; what do you intend to do with the examples?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of https://www.gov.uk/

And the Swedish government website https://www.government.se/

They are doing a great job and they invest a lot in user research before launching anything. I don't think I can share any screenshots but you can get a feeling of how well that website is organised.

Comment: I'd beg to differ on gov.uk.  With exception of the extremely useful MOT history site: https://www.gov.uk/check-mot-history

Comment: I'm not saying it's perfect. I think they are doing a good job. As a user, I always achieved what I wanted to do on their website without having to call and ask for help.